# Using URL within Vhost container with mod_perl dynamically

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, mod-perl, virtualhost

We want to retrieve URL and use it inside our vhosts, realtime.

To demonstrate my case, I placed random numbers on ServerAdmin directive,

$ServerAdmin = int(rand(100))."loko\@koko.com";

As you may know, this random number is assigned only when you restart the server, and never changes until another restart.

> This is what we want:  if
>   julie.myperl.com is the requested
>   domain, then $ServerAdmin =
>   julie@myperl.com, that is, realtime.

Hopefully there is a solution, since this will help us remove thousands of config files, and save us from thousands of apache reloads.

Thanks,
Devrim

here is kind of similar situation and solution,

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

and here is why ask this question,
we have built an API in which subdomains signify unix account names,
so variable part of {$user}.domain.com must be used within vhost conf.
[Using variables within Apache virtualhost containers](https://serverfault.com/questions/84582/using-variables-within-apache-virtualhost-containers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question a while back that may help you.  Basically it's a bit of perl that will do any sort of dynamic configuration based on the url.  In that example it was setting the Require directive based on the directory, but with a tiny bit of adjustment it should do what you need as well.

Take a look here: [Dynamic authentication realms in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/75010/dynamic-authentication-realms-in-apache/75526#75526)

Hope that helps.

**Edit**: This should to do it.  I used `server_admin` to manipulate the server admin address directly rather than `add_config` because `add_config` acts like a `<Directory>` block, and `ServerAdmin` isn't allowed there.

```
<Perl>
 use Apache2::ServerRec qw//;
 use Apache2::ServerUtil qw//;
 use Apache2::RequestRec qw//;
 use Apache2::RequestUtil qw//;
 use Apache2::Const qw/OK DECLINED/;

 my $s = Apache2::ServerUtil->server;

 $s->push_handlers(PerlHeaderParserHandler => sub { my($r) = @_;
  if ( $r->hostname =~ m/(.*)\.([^.]+\.\w+)$/ ) {
   my($subdomain,$domain) = ($1,$2);

   eval{
    $r->server->server_admin("$subdomain\@$domain");
   };
   if ( $@ ) { warn $@ }

   return OK;

  } else {
   return DECLINED;
  }
 });
</Perl>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, this is exactly what I am looking for, and it's very very important. I couldn't change your script, could you help me out? I just need {*} part of any {*}.domain.com to be assigned to $1, I can do the rest. I'd really really appreciate your 5 mins on this! Thanks!

Comment: Answer updated.  Took a bit more than five minutes, but it was fun to mess with. ;-) Let me know if that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Awesome! Please drop me a note at devrim at kodingen.com if you are up to some consulting, we need these perl hacks for perfect configuration... Thanks again!

Comment: I actually am having difficulty adjusting this regex.. I think Perl using slightly different syntax. I have to push this variable to <IfModule mpm_itk_module> AssignUserId $subdomain $subdomain </IfModule> . I was able to do this before: $IfModule{"mpm_itk_module"} = {AssignUserId => "devrim devrim"}; now this didn't work within your snippet..

Comment: `$r->add_config(["AssignUserId $subdomain $subdomain"]);` may work.  Please try it.  If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to approach this problem from another angle.

Comment: Jeff, I've been working on it day and night, I think I am so close but I'm getting this: $r->add_config() has failed: AssignUserID not allowed here. here is my line: $r->add_config([      "<IfModule mpm_itk_module>",        
                        "AssignUserID devrim devrim",
                        "</IfModule>",
                 ]);
I wrote to every Perl forum, but nobody seems to be of help. I'd appreciate if you consider. Thanks.

Comment: * AssignUserID is actually AssignUserId

Comment: Devrim, I'll email you.  This is getting to be a lot of discussion to get working and I don't think it's appropriate to do on SF.