# Routing Apache TracEnv

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, trac

i have a situation with many trac instances. They all have the same structure in the filesystem.

```
PATH/trac1
PATH/trac2
PATH/trac3
```

i have this configuration

```
<Location /trac/trac1>
 SetHandler mod_python
 PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
 PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend 
 PythonOption TracEnv PATH/trac1
 PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac/trac1
 PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE PATH/eggs/
</Location>
<Location /trac/trac2>
 SetHandler mod_python
 PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
 PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend 
 PythonOption TracEnv PATH/trac2
 PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac/trac2
 PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE PATH/eggs/
</Location>
<Location /trac/trac3>
 SetHandler mod_python
 PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
 PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend 
 PythonOption TracEnv PATH/trac3
 PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac/trac3
 PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE PATH/eggs/
</Location>
```

i wonder if it's possible to do something like (**TracEnvParentDir is not an option**)

```
<Location /trac/{ENV}>
 SetHandler mod_python
 PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
 PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend 
 PythonOption TracEnv PATH/{ENV}
 PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac/{ENV}
 PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE PATH/eggs/
</Location>
```

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** TracEnvParentDir is not an option because my structure is the following

```
+---projs
    +---trac1
    ¦   +---public [instance]
    ¦   +---t1
    ¦   ¦   +---common [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g1 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g2 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g3 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g4 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g5 [instance]
    ¦   +---t2
    ¦   ¦   +---common [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g1 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g2 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g3 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g4 [instance]
    ¦   ¦   +---g5 [instance]
    ¦   +---t3
    ¦       +---common [instance]
    ¦       +---g1 [instance]
    ¦       +---g2 [instance]
    ¦       +---g3 [instance]
    ¦       +---g4 [instance]
    ¦       +---g5 [instance]
    ¦  
    +---trac2
        +---public [instance]
        +---t1
        ¦   +---common [instance]
        ¦   +---g1 [instance]
        ¦   +---g2 [instance]
        ¦   +---g3 [instance]
        ¦   +---g4 [instance]
        ¦   +---g5 [instance]
        +---t2
        ¦   +---common [instance]
        ¦   +---g1 [instance]
        ¦   +---g2 [instance]
        ¦   +---g3 [instance]
        ¦   +---g4 [instance]
        ¦   +---g5 [instance]
        +---t3
            +---common [instance]
            +---g1 [instance]
            +---g2 [instance]
            +---g3 [instance]
            +---g4 [instance]
            +---g5 [instance]
```

I use the **TracEnvParentDir** on t1, t2 and t3
and **TracEnv** on trac1/public and trac2/public

**I wonder if it's possible to define a part of the url variable.**

Comment: Can you explain why `TracEnvParentDir` is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to switch to mod_wsgi instead of modpython, and see my answer here how to do what you want: [Dynamic subdomains, mod_python and trac](https://serverfault.com/questions/111000/dynamic-subdomains-mod-python-and-trac/111320#111320)

Answer (score 0):

The official mod_wsgi documentation on integrating Trac with mod_wsgi tells you about how to do this. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac